# Java, Recommended way to Persist HashMaps for permanent, Reliable storage?

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

I am working on a project where a lot of searches are being conducted on a very large set of data so I am realizing using a traditional database structure itsn't working as I need to read tables into a HashMap format, that stays in memory the entire time, to be able to run queries in the amount of time needed for the application performance.

I am wondering what the recommended process for peristing a HashMap is with regard to speed of retrieving them from their persistent state and regard to minimizing extra code needed (as now I am writing custom classes that read the necessary data from DB tables and then create a nested HashMap reflecting the data structure that I need it to be in to be searchable as quickly as possible. I am not sure if simply writing to a text file would be a proper way to do this with regards to making sure the data is preserved and not corrupted. Any advice is appreciated

Comment: This is probably relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832622/java-large-persistent-hash-structure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered using key-value databases (like Redis or Riak)?

Comment: I am not familiar with those but am definitely going to check it out, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2):

1. [Ehcache](http://ehcache.org/).
2. [disk-backed-map](http://code.google.com/p/disk-backed-map/)

The following post might also help you

[recommend-a-fast-scalable-persistent-map-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536953/recommend-a-fast-scalable-persistent-map-java)

Answer (score 2):

If you are sticking content from your DB into a hash structure in order to speed up searches against DB content I think you're probably taking the wrong approach. I don't know what you're trying to do exactly but perhaps using an index like [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) is appropriate? This is a mature and highly optimised index and will handle things like caching frequent queries in memory.

Alternatively take a look at [BerkeleyDB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/overview/inde) which is basically a disk-backed hash DB. Also very fast. (Although note I believe Oracle may be requiring a license for this for some use-cases now).

The only caveats to Lucene and BerkeleyDB is that they will require some overhead to set up. So my last suggestion is [Tokyo-Cabinet](http://fallabs.com/tokyocabinet/) which is a pretty decent, very quick and very simple to use disk-backed hash. Basically just include the jar in your class path and use it like a HashMap:

```
import tokyocabinet.HDB;

....

String dir = "/path/to/my/dir/";
HDB hash = new HDB();

// open the hash for read/write, create if does not exist on disk
if (!hash.open(dir + "unigrams.tch", HDB.OWRITER | HDB.OCREAT)) {
    throw new IOException("Unable to open " + dir + "unigrams.tch: " + hash.errmsg());
}

// Add something to the hash
hash.put("blah", "my string");

// Close it
hash.close();
```

And that's it. Anything you stick in the hash is persisted to disk, and can be reloaded later. And don't worry about the speed, in-memory optimisations are handled for you behind the scenes.

**Edit:** It looks like Tokyo Cabinet has been superceded by [Kyoto Cabinet](http://fallabs.com/kyotocabinet/).

**Edit 2:** You don't say what DB you're using, but if MySQL does [full text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) not work for you?

Comment: After doing more research into this I think that using a relational database has definite disadvantages, in my case, compared to a NoSQL database (something I just became familiar with the concept of). I am working on a search engine application so I think getting away from the relational DB is necessary, anyways, thanks for the info, Kyoto Cabinet is something I am definitely considering using now