# Stanford NLP tools and lots of text

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm currently using the Stanford CoreNLP tools to extract triplets from text. I've been dealing with relatively small pieces of text, but I need to make it work with larger ones. Also, I need this work on the average machine with an average amount of memory. Any suggestions on how I can reduce the memory load? Perhaps split the text into smaller pieces (this would screw up coreference however...)?

Thank you

Comment: The dependency coreference system only looks out 4 sentences so you are pretty safe. If it is a large amount of text you may lose a reference or two but it's probably acceptable, depending on what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

A brute force method: use a off heap memory (using disk space as a memory for Java program), see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832622/java-large-persistent-hash-structure/3853707#3853707) or [go here to learn more about BigMemory library](http://ehcache.org/documentation/offheap_store.html#Configuring_caches_to_overflow_to_off-heap). Slow but it might be what you are looking for.